# Set a pointer to point to user input C++

Tags: c++, pointers

What I am trying to do is to have a pointer pointing to user input without creating extra variable. Something like this:

```
    system("CLS");
    cout << endl << "Please enter your expression:" << endl;        
    *expression->infix = &cin>>;
```

Obviously this doesn't compile, is there any way of doing something like this without creating an extra variable for storing the user input and then pointing to it?

Comment: If you aren't storing it where do you expect your pointer to point to?

Comment: You take the input from a stream. Pointers can't point to streams.

Comment: @AkshayArora, why not? Pointers, of course, can point to streams.

Comment: Why do you even need a pointer to it?  take in a `std::string` and then pass it around by reference.

Comment: @SergeyA Thank you, would you please give me an example of how i can set my pointer to point to stream?

Comment: @SergeyA, Is it? Well.. I learnt something today.

Comment: @NaughtyNinja, but that would be a pointer to the stream itself. What are you going to do with that?

Comment: @SergeyA I'm gonna be passing this user input across different classes all i want is to make sure i'm not copying the same value multiple times. That's why i just wanted to create a pointer pointing to user input.

Comment: @AkshayArora, certainly. `std::ostream* ptr = &std::cout;`

Comment: @NaughtyNinja, there is a reason why a stream is called stream. It it's a stream of data. You can't get a pointer directly into stream's data, all you can do is *stream the data out* from the stream (operator `>>`) into some variable and than use it.

Comment: @SergeyA Well explained, thank you. At least now i am aware what i can and what i cannot do, since i am new to c++ and pointers particularly.

Comment: @SergeyA You can get pointer to stream data by `rdbuf()` and much more than that?

Comment: @AngelusMortis, no, this is a pointer to stream's buffer. It is not stream data as in 'data which will be extracted from the stream'

Comment: @SergeyA yes and you can use that pointer to access real buffer by using `streambuf`'s public interface

Comment: @AngelusMortis, no. All you can do using **public** interface is read next character without advancing the buffer or extract n characters and advance it. Using **protected** interface you can obtain a pointer to *get area*, which is not guaranteed to have any data whatsoever.

Comment: @SergeyA public interface provides enough to do low level IO operations and protected interface is mostly for stream implementer. If you mean that one accesses buffer directly than that's hard to do, which is not meant to do in fact.

Comment: @AngelusMortis, you are so deeply confused, that I see no reason to continue this discussion. If you have an idea in mind, you can post this in the answer.

Comment: @SergeyA well I agree to disagree, sayonara :)

Comment: @AngelusMortis, this is not a question of opinions, it is a technical discussion. You can not avail yourself to 'agree to disagree' argument in technical discussions.

Comment: @SergeyA "you are so deeply confused" <- to that my reply was, and I concede, you're sooo right when it comes to technical discussion that I truly feel noob in C++ again (which I always been) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cin` is an `istream` representing the [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) of the OS. In Linux, for example, reading from a stream entails issuing the `read` syscall. The input might not even be typed yet, and even if it is, it would most likely be buffered in kernel memory until you read it. So there is no way for you to point into this memory. The best you can do is to read it into user-space memory and point into that memory.

EDIT: to clarify I would line to add that the `istream` *might* have an additional internal buffer in your process's memory for performance reasons (see `rdbuf`). But  you wouldn't want to point into that buffer even if you could, since its data would be changed over time as data is passing through the stream.

Comment: Thank you, hopefully other beginners will be able to learn from this example.